# Obtaining an EU Blue Card with No Degree (Opening a current US Company)

Tags: working-visas, germany, eu, resident-permit, blue-card

From reading online it looks like i need the following:

Usually the employee must have a university degree or comparable qualification. For some positions there are special requirements.

I don't have a University degree, can I still obtain a EU Blue Card (Germany)? I have looked online but have found nothing in regards to my current company relocating me to open up shop and staff all local employees.

Comment: Note that the EU blue card is not the only visa/residence permit available in Germany (or in any EU country). It's simply a different type of residence permit, added on top of the national visa system of each participating country. I must say that I am not completely sure I understand your situation but it seems another visa might be more appropriate.

Comment: I guess in other words I am "highly skilled" for this position and a Blue Card was the first thing mentioned. I needed to look into the requirements. We currently have partners we offer a service to, for their local German companies. I need to staff 50+ German speaking employees. Sounds like another Visa is my best option, I will have to do some further research.

Comment: You could also ask a new question about that, providing as many details as possible. Meanwhile, since it seems my answer fully addresses the current question, would you consider accepting it to “close” the question?

Comment: Hi @Seth - which visa did you get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot.

Both the EU directive and German law include a provision to allow the authorities to exempt applicants from the education requirement based on their professional experience but the relevant federal ministry in Germany [hasn't enacted the regulation (*Verordnung*) that would be necessary to implement it](http://www.bamf.de/DE/Infothek/FragenAntworten/BlaueKarteEU/blaue-karte-eu-node.html) so that it remains impossible for the moment.