# Bluecard vs Long-Term Visa

Tags: working-visas, germany, eu, blue-card

I currently work in the IT field (as an Security Analyst) and I am in the works of moving to Germany. I've got a job offer from my employer but unsure whether I qualify for an EU Bluecard.

All the EU Bluecard requirements are met beside the University Degree. I am certified as an Security Analyst, have some other certifications done and 2 years of courses completed at a university but with no degree/diploma. I read that you need a University degree or 5 years or more experience in this field.
I currently have over 7 years of experience in IT. Do I qualify for an EU Bluecard? Would it be easier to have a lawyer representing me? Any good lawyers someone could suggest in the Dortmund/Bielefeld/Munster region?

Comment: There is a much clearer answer at https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6363/obtaining-an-eu-blue-card-with-no-degree-opening-a-current-us-company/6364#6364 Basically, in Germany (but not necessarily in other EU countries), you need a degree, no exception.

Comment: @Relaxed This is not correct, § 19a (1)(1)(b) states clearly **if he has a comparable qualification demonstrated by at least five years of professional experience**. That should be considered an exception.

Comment: @MarkJohnson That's not exactly what it states, you omited half of the sentence, the key is in “to the extent that this is stipulated by a statutory instrument pursuant to subsection 2 below”. Did you follow the link I provided? The bit you quoted has been in the law (and the directive) since the beginning but it remains void without the “statutory instrument“ in question.

Comment: @Relaxed Your conclusion is incorrect since you are not taking into account 19.2.3 of the [General administrative regulation for the Residence Act](http://www.verwaltungsvorschriften-im-internet.de/bsvwvbund_26102009_MI31284060.htm) of 2009 (and is still valid in 2021): 'For the group of people according to number 3, the assumption of "high qualifications" is justified by their professional experience and professional position.' **Note**: After 2012, group #3 applied to peaple covered in §19a.

Comment: @Relaxed Since March 2021 the main prerequirement is that the skilled worker has a qualification that enables them to carry out the desired job.

Comment: @MarkJohnson March 2021 is in two months from now, what are you referring to? Regarding the *Allgemeine Verwaltungsvorschrift zum Aufenthaltsgesetz*, can you provide a proper citation (page or paragraph number, quote in German)? If that has been the case since 2012, how come the BAMF says otherwise? Why did you bother mentioning § 19a (1)(1)(b) while conspicuously failing to quote half of it? And why does it mention a statutory instrument that would have been moot from the start as the EU blue card system was created in 2009?

Comment: @Relaxed **19.2.3** is on the PDF page 120. The first line is quoted ('Bei dem Personenkreis nach Nummer 3 ist die Annahme der „Hochqualifikation“ durch ihre Berufserfahrung und berufliche Stellung gerechtfertigt.'). The rest of the paragraph deals with the salary conditions. Effective 1. August 2012, §19(3) was moved to its own paragraph §19a. If you really want to know why they did this, **write them and ask**.

Comment: @Relaxed, ouflak As to why BAMF ignores this point in the regulation that has existed since 26th of  October 2009 in their FAQ, you would have to ask them. FAQ's aren't always correct as you *should* know. I **did** look it up when I wrote the now deleted answer and quoted the **relavent** portion of §19a. You preferred to rely solely on the FAQ (to which you didn't even bother to give a link to).

Comment: @MarkJohnson I am not basing this solely on the FAQ but also on the text of the law itself. You cannot “forget” half of a sentence without any explanation. 2012 is actually when the 2009 directive was implemented in German law. 19.2.3 obviously deals with something else (and in particular with a *Niederlassungserlaubnis*). Your new theory is even more contorted than usual and there are many confusions to unpack. Since the faulty answer has been deleted and the correct one is in the other question, I think I will abstain from playing your little games this time around.

Comment: You still have a bunch of other demonstrably false answers to correct, though.

Comment: Also relevant: https://www.bamf.de/SharedDocs/Anlagen/DE/Forschung/Forschungsberichte/fb27-blaue-karte-eu.pdf, especially the recommandation in 5.3 pp. 113 sq.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the process of applying for a European Blue Card for working in the IT sector in Paris.

Here are the conditions:

1. You must have a Diploma leading to at least 3 years of higher education.
2. You must have a contract of employment equal to or greater than 12 months justifying a minimum annual remuneration of 54K

Comment: I understand that a university degree is a requirement but it says that you might meet the requirement if you have 5 or more years experience in that field. Is that somehting I could rely on and apply ? Or is is safer to go with a long-term work visa...will I be able to bring my family with me with a work visa?